# How to insert into a POJO into a key-value database table?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

What's the easiest way to insert the POJO into a ***key-value table*** below with Spring's `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` **without manually looping** through each field and calling insert?

The POJO:

```
class Person {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   int age;
   ...many more fields
}
```

**key-value** `person_attributes` Table:

```
attribute      | value
---------------------
 firstName     | Bob
 lastName      | Billy
 age           | 30
```

Comment: http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/using-namedparameterjdbctemplate-in.html#.VngzR5MrLq0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson's [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) class to convert POJO to key value pair

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> personMap = mapper.convertValue(person, Map.class);
```

Then iterate over each map entry and insert into the database

Alternatively you can use [Apache commons beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html)

Comment: I was hoping Spring has a way of mapping the fields into a single column without having a loop over the fields manually..but I suppose this is the closest solution...

Answer (score 1):

BeanPropertySqlParameterSource is the best way:

```
Person person = .....

String sql = "insert into Person (first_Name, Last_Name, age) " + 
                   "values (:firstName, :lastName, :age)"; 
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(person));
```

A complete example here:
http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data-access-with-jdbc/named-param-jdbc-template-example/

Comment: This is nice but different than what I asked. Your example uses `BeanPropertySqlParameterSource` to map **each field to its column**. What I'm asking for is mapping **each field to the same column named attribute**.